# RoR render partial with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble rendering a partial with javascript.

I need the javascript to be part of the document, but for some reason when inspecting the document the javascript is not there.

Is there a way to render a partial with javascript so it is part of the document?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using erb templates, then make sure you are using the proper tags. Something like this <%= render :partial => 'mypartial' %>, so that the content of that partial shows up.

In that partial, you can have some javascript code inside some script tags.

Comment: And then use that javascript code to render your actual seperate haml/html partial.